# Publish failure: "Sequence contains no elements" in ProcessActivity

Tags: 2013, publishing, bundles

I am publishing a component using a bundle and it goes through review-staging-live workflow processes. However at the last step where it is supposed to be pushed to live, below error is occurring. I am not sure what it means, any idea on what could be wrong or how to debug would be helpful

System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements at Tridion.ContentManager.Workflow.WorkflowAgentEngine.ProcessActivity(TcmUri activityInstanceId)

Comment: Could it be because the items are _not_ in workflow anymore at the time they're published, since this is an asynchronous task? I've seen solutions where we add one more workflow step (automatic) before actually finishing the workflow, and in this step we check if the bundle was successfully published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause turned out to be email ids not being mapped to some of the users in the environment.We were populating the emails ids in a list and having some functionality on top of that. So when the email id list didn't contain any values, this error was thrown.